# scrapy formrequest producing mismatched and missing results

Tags: python, scrapy

I am running a series of formrequests in scrapy, jumping from one page to the next, while going from one row to the next within a page, and scraping document numbers and names from each row.

However, the scraped data when outputted to a csv seems to appear mismatched and sometimes missing. Any idea why this is the case?

```
    formdata_pre={
            'ScriptManager1' : "SearchFormEx1$UpdatePanel|SearchFormEx1$btnSearch",
            'ScriptManager1_HiddenField': '', 
            'Navigator1$SearchOptions1$SavePrintCriteriaCheck' : 'on',
            'Navigator1$SearchOptions1$SaveOrderCriteriaCheck' : 'on',
            'SearchCriteriaOffice1$DDL_OfficeName' : 'Recorded Land',
            'SearchCriteriaName1$DDL_SearchName' : 'Recorded Land Name Search',
            'SearchFormEx1$ACSTextBox_LastName1' : 'mortgage electronic',
            'SearchFormEx1$ACSTextBox_FirstName1' : '',
            'SearchFormEx1$ACSRadioButtonList_PartyType1' : '',
            'SearchFormEx1$ACSTextBox_LastName2' : '',
            'SearchFormEx1$ACSTextBox_FirstName2' : '',
            'SearchFormEx1$ACSRadioButtonList_PartyType2' : '',
            'SearchFormEx1$ACSRadioButtonList_Search' : '3',
            'SearchFormEx1$ACSDropDownList_DocumentType' : '29',
            'SearchFormEx1$ACSDropDownList_Towns' : '-2',
            'SearchFormEx1$ACSTextBox_DateFrom' : '1/1/1753',
            'SearchFormEx1$ACSTextBox_DateTo' : '10/14/2000',
            'ImageViewer1$ScrollPos' : '',
            'ImageViewer1$ScrollPosChange' : '',
            'ImageViewer1$_imgContainerWidth' : '0',
            'ImageViewer1$_imgContainerHeight' : '0',
            'ImageViewer1$isImageViewerVisible' : 'true',
            'ImageViewer1$hdnWidgetSize' : '',
            'ImageViewer1$DragResizeExtender_ClientState' : '',
            'CertificateViewer1$ScrollPos' : '',
            'CertificateViewer1$ScrollPosChange' : '',
            'CertificateViewer1$_imgContainerWidth' : '0',
            'CertificateViewer1$_imgContainerHeight' : '0',
            'CertificateViewer1$isImageViewerVisible' : 'true',
            'CertificateViewer1$hdnWidgetSize' : '',
            'CertificateViewer1$DragResizeExtender_ClientState' : '',
            'PTAXViewer1$ScrollPos' : '',
            'PTAXViewer1$ScrollPosChange' : '',
            'PTAXViewer1$_imgContainerWidth' : '0',
            'PTAXViewer1$_imgContainerHeight' : '0',
            'PTAXViewer1$isImageViewerVisible' : 'true',
            'PTAXViewer1$hdnWidgetSize' : '',
            'PTAXViewer1$DragResizeExtender_ClientState' : '',
            'DocList1$ctl12' : '',
            'DocList1$ctl14' : '',
            'RefinementCtrl1$ctl01' : '',
            'RefinementCtrl1$ctl03' : '',
            'NameList1$ScrollPos' : '',
            'NameList1$ScrollPosChange' : '',
            'NameList1$_SortExpression' : '',
            'NameList1$ctl03' : '',
            'NameList1$ctl05' : '',
            'DocDetails1$PageSize' : '',
            'DocDetails1$PageIndex' : '',
            'DocDetails1$SortExpression' : '',
            'BasketCtrl1$ctl01' : '',
            'BasketCtrl1$ctl03' : '',
            'OrderList1$ctl01' : '',
            'OrderList1$ctl03' : '',
            '__EVENTTARGET' : '',
            '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
            '__LASTFOCUS' : '',
            '__VIEWSTATE' : '',
            '__ASYNCPOST' : 'true',
            'SearchFormEx1$btnSearch' : 'Search'
            }
```

Above is the formdata_pre for the formdata below--stack overflow is being weird about this dict.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import FormRequest
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
import re

class FormySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'formy'
    allowed_domains = ['i2a.uslandrecords.com']
    start_urls = ['https://i2a.uslandrecords.com/ME/Cumberland/D/Default.aspx']
    def parse(self, response):
        URL = 'https://i2a.uslandrecords.com/ME/Cumberland/D/Default.aspx'
        headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'}        
        yield FormRequest(url=URL, 
            method='POST',
            headers = headers,
            formdata={
            'ScriptManager1' : 'Navigator1$SearchOptions1$UpdatePanel|Navigator1$SearchOptions1$DocImagesCheck',
            '__EVENTTARGET' : 'Navigator1$SearchOptions1$DocImagesCheck',
            '__ASYNCPOST' : ' true'},
            dont_filter=True,
            callback=self.after_login_1
            )

    def after_login_1(self, response):        
        URL = 'https://i2a.uslandrecords.com/ME/Cumberland/D/Default.aspx'
        headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'}        
        formdata=formdata_pre,
        yield FormRequest(url=URL,
            method='POST',
            headers = headers,
            formdata=formdata,
            dont_filter=True,
            callback=self.after_login_2
            )

    def after_login_2(self, response):
        URL = 'https://i2a.uslandrecords.com/ME/Cumberland/D/Default.aspx'
        headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'}        
        if response.xpath("(//a[contains(@id,'ButtonRow_Doc')])[1]").get():            print(response.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'LinkButton')]/text()").getall())            print(response.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'ButtonRow_Doc')]/text()").getall())
            for row in response.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'ButtonRow_Doc')]/@href").getall():
                event =re.findall(r'doPostBack\(\'([^()].*)\'\,\'\'\)',row)[0]
                scriptmanager = 'DocList1$UpdatePanel|'+event
                ndoc=re.findall(r'\#\_(.*)\'\,',row)[0]
                nbook = response.xpath( "(//a[contains(@href,\"_{}',\")])[3]/text()".format(ndoc)).get()                
                npage = response.xpath( "(//a[contains(@href,\"_{}',\")])[4]/text()".format(ndoc)).get()
                yield FormRequest(url=URL, 
                    method='POST',
                    headers = headers,
                    formdata={
                    'ScriptManager1' : scriptmanager,
                    '__EVENTTARGET' : event,
                    '__ASYNCPOST' : ' true'},
                    dont_filter=True,
                    meta = {
                    'nbook' : nbook,
                    'npage' : npage
                    },
                    callback=self.after_login_3
                    )                
                if response.xpath("//a[@id='DocList1_LinkButtonNext']").get():            

                    yield FormRequest(url=URL, 
                        method='POST',
                        headers = headers,
                        formdata={
                        'ScriptManager1' : 'DocList1$UpdatePanel|DocList1$LinkButtonNext',
                        '__EVENTTARGET' : 'DocList1$LinkButtonNext',
                        '__ASYNCPOST' : ' true'},
                        dont_filter=True,
                        callback=self.after_login_2
                        )
                else:            
                    print("empty week")

    def after_login_3(self, response):
        URL = 'https://i2a.uslandrecords.com/ME/Cumberland/D/Default.aspx'
        headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'}
        names  = response.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'GrantorGrantee')]/text()").getall()
        nbook = response.request.meta['nbook']
        npage = response.request.meta['npage']
        yield {        
        'nbook' : nbook,
        'npage' : npage,
        'names' : names
        }
```

In terms of output, here is an example of a mismatch:

15643 ||    20  || {FRANTZ RICHARD C  ,MORTGAGE ELECTRONIC REGISTRATION SYSTEMS INC   ,FLEET MORTGAGE CORP}

In the above, the names do not match with the page and book numbers and the name "HUGHES ANDREW" is entirely absent. This is just one example.

I think that the scrapy request is going too fast for the response to produce, and maybe this lag is creating the disconnect and missing objects.

Comment: Please show your code and output mismatch example.

Comment: Sorry, just added the code

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provided code or output so it's kind of hard to help you. **It sounds like** the page show results based on your session, since the Scrapy request are concurrent the sessions might be overlapping.

You can set the requests for each session with the param  `meta={'cookiejar': different_values_here}`, you can read more [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#multiple-cookie-sessions-per-spider).

Comment: I just added the code and a line of output as well. I just tried the cookiejar, and now the names field is coming up empty